# Connection refused by Raspberry PI 3b+

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I would like to access my raspberry PI from outside my network using ssh.
When I am inside the same network it works perfectly.
But as soon as I want to connect from the outside and type in the password, it says:

> Permission denied, please try again.

The command ssh -vv pi@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx gives me the following output:

https://pastebin.com/v02vzqxB

I replaced my IP with "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Have you setup port forwarding on your router? And if so, are you using  your public IP address when you ssh as opposed to the private IP address you're using when connecting from internally?

Comment: Yes, port 22 is open and relates to my PI.
When I ssh in my network, I use the 192.168.xxx.xxx to access my PI direct and when I try to shh from outside my network I am using the public IP-adress of my router

Comment: Most likely your problem is either a wrongly configured  port forwarding or you are behind a [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). A screenshot of your port forwarding configuration would help. (Unless that it what your pastebin link is showing; if so, my apologies since I'm at work and pastebin is blocked).

Comment: Okay thank you for your help, I used pastebin because the output of the console is quite ugly :D
I will check your answer later when I am at home

Comment: If I interpret the pastebin correctly, you have no problem connecting, but authenticating.  Are you trying to connect as root?